# Android device not recognized in eclipse

Tags: usb, android, eclipse

I tried to plug my Samsung Galaxy S to my Ubuntu box for developing applications in Android, but the problem is that `lsusb` doesn't recognize the device.

I tried with a friend smartphone and it is recognized, but mine is not.

Any idea?

Comment: The android of your friend have the same android version? As `2.2`, `3.4`, `4.1`..

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on the web reveals that you have to activate debugging on the phone first.

Comment: I did it already, but no luck.